# Shehechiyanu when lighting in shul

Tags: halacha, blessing, chanuka, synagogue, shehecheyanu

The bracha *Shehechiyanu* is supposed to be said only once during Chanukah, namely upon the first lighting (which is usually the 1st night unless someone was unable to light on the 1st night.)

The candles are lit in shul also, and a bracha is said in shul. However, a person does not fulfill his obligation via the lighting in shul, and he must relight when he arrives home.

Being that the person who lit in shul has already said *Shehechiyanu* in shul, does this not count at all, since the actual mitzvah is to light at home, does this mean that he can and should say *Shehechiyanu* when he arrives home - meaning he would say it twice in the same night?

Comment: "Shehechiyanu is supposed to be said only once during Chanukah" Source? Maybe it's just generally said once?

Comment: Note Shehechiyanu could be recited on seeing the candles as well in certain circumstances.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'll see if I can locate a source. But, I wouldn't generalize that *Shehechiyanu* is said just once for each mitzvah occurrence. We see that for lulav it is only once. But it's not once for either Shofar or Megillah. There may be different rules occurring there. It may warrant a separate question.

Comment: most communities only say it once on megillah (eg. most sefardim, yemenites, yekkes, vilna gaon, etc.)

Comment: related posts about [shofar](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/21806/759) and [lulav](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10704/759) and [sukkah](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/20538/759)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sha'arei Teshuva](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&st=&pgnum=277) on O.C. 671 sk 14 says that if one has lit at home first, said *Shehechiyanu* and then lights in shul, he should say *Shehechiyanu* in shul. However, if he lit in shul first and said *Shehechiyanu* there, he should not repeat it when he gets home unless he is fulfilling his wife's obligation by lighting for her.

(I'm not quite understanding the reason why the shul lighting is considered more important with respect to *Shehechiyanu*)

Comment: Probably because the Tzibur needs to have a shehechiyanu represented on the first night, so for that sake, it needs to be said even if that particular person doesn't need to.

Comment: @DavidKenner It's an interesting argument. I'm still trying to gain a batter understanding of what the bracha is for. Is it the lighting or the *pirsumei nissa*. If it's the 1st notion, then, I don't know why brachot are made in shul altogether.